# How to find import statements that are required for the block/method declaration in AST Eclipse JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

This is my code snippet, here I try to create a new class from a extracted block from another class. Now I need to find what are all import statements required in the method that is extracted which has be added to the generated class.

```
private void generateClass() throws IOException {

    AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS8);
    CompilationUnit unit = ast.newCompilationUnit();

    TypeDeclaration type = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
    type.setInterface(false);
    type.modifiers().add(ast.newModifier(Modifier.ModifierKeyword.PUBLIC_KEYWORD));
    type.setName(ast.newSimpleName("GeneratedClass"));

    MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration = identifyASTNode.getMethodDeclaration();
    methodDeclaration = (MethodDeclaration)ASTNode.copySubtree(ast, methodDeclaration);

    type.bodyDeclarations().add(methodDeclaration);

    unit.types().add(type);

    writeToFile(unit.toString());
}
```